# How to increase dimensions of filepond drop area in React.js?

Tags: reactjs, filepond

I have a FilePond component used to upload files in my React App with the following implementation :

```
~~~React.js 

   render() {
    return (
        <div className="App">

           //Pass FilePond properties as attributes
          <FilePond
                      ref={ref => this.pond = ref}
                      files={this.state.files}
                      allowMultiple={false}
                      maxFiles={1}
                      onupdatefiles={(fileItems) => {
                         //add image to database 
                      }
            </FilePond>

~~~
```

This code renders [a nice looking component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zuTpb.png) to let users upload their files.

However I would like to scale up (edit width and height) this component taken from https://pqina.nl/filepond/. Unfortunately I can seem to find a way to do that, can someone please help me ?

Comment: what size would you like it to be?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

On their documentation they [recommend overriding their styles](https://pqina.nl/filepond/docs/patterns/api/style/). So you can do the same, just adjust the height of whatever you need to.

```
.filepond--root,
.filepond--root .filepond--drop-label {
  height: 200px;
}
```

## [**See it live!**](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-filepond-live-demo-x9io9)

Comment: @Volck yep! happy to help! remember you can open the developer console, and look at the elements. find the class names you need to update and then apply the styles to those classes :)

Comment: Hi. Please look at my question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/58471218/1767712